# Add "log out globally" button on user popup

Tags: feature-request, logout, stack-exchange-openid

I propose adding a "log out globally" button on user pop-up to fast log out from all Stack Exchange pages. Why enter a [OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) page and then logout if we can have one button ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot work, because you need to log out of your *OpenID provider*. That is **not** a Stack Exchange function, nor can Stack Exchange do that for you.

For example, if you are using Google as your OpenID login to Stack Exchange sites, the link you propose would have to log you out of Google. That means you would be logged out of GMail, Google Calendar, Google+, etc., etc. That would be a heinous breach of site security.

Of course, there is also a Stack Exchange OpenID provider, which theoretically could support such a link. But that doesn't mean that users use *only* that provider; it is perfectly feasible to have both Google and Stack Exchange Open IDs added to your account. Which one would be logged out when you use that link?

Comment: And even for those who are using the Stack Exchange OpenID, this would  make things confusing if one *also* has an alternative OpenID configured. (Though I guess there's little need for that, when using Stack Exchange OpenID.) In that case, from *which* OpenID provider to log out?

Comment: I've been wondering though if there could be a more clear indication of what logging out actually means on SO/SE. Or rather what it doesn't mean. This confusion seems to come up time and time again.

Comment: Currently nearly nothing seems to work. Even when I log out of my OpenId provider, I still stay logged in SO. Even when I log out of SO, I still stay logged in Meta. And so on. A button invalidating all SO sessions at once *can* work.