# Can we have proper logout instructions when using open id?

Tags: feature-request, openid, logout

It will be helpful for beginners if a proper log out message is shown accordingly when using open ids. Please don't make another beginner to search the question related to "log out open id" again in here. How will people know that their gmail or ymail is still not signed out, if nothing is mentioned?

Not every users of stack exchange will not be aware of cookies and open id working. They just logout and hope that their accounts are safe.

For example, I am using login with gmail option.

We can have a small message like this:

"Reminder: Please be make sure that your corresponding open id is also signed out after this" in the log out page.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/why-am-i-stilled-logged-into-gmail-and-stackoverflow-after-logging-out-of-stac

Comment: Related: [Add "log out globally" button on user popup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190844)

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you want more detailed instructions added to the log out screen? Where should we put them? Or possibly the Help Center? What should they say?

Comment: Edited question with the message I am expecting and this exactly what I was asking for....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenID does not provide a proper way to logout centrally.

Anyway, I think doing so would be counterproductive anyway (except when using the StackExchange login) since any other site that also uses OpenID would leave the user logged in on the OpenID provider's site.

The only thing I could imagine is showing a message like "Please don't forget to logout from your OpenID provider, too, if this is a public/shared computer."

Comment: That would be nice in the interest of being good netizens, not a bad idea.